# Why i get nothing from my servlet?

Tags: android, servlets, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a simple dictionary. The user input is a word in english and it has to be translated into french by using a servlet. The code looks ok, I mean I get no errors. But I get nothing when I run it!
How do I get this to show the translated word?. Thanks, - Steve
My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivityDictionary extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        HttpClient httpClient;
        Button btn;
        EditText edEng;
        TextView tv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_ord_bok);

            findViewsById();
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void findViewsById() {
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEngFr);
            edEng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEng);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFr);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnEngFr:
                    doTranslation(); break;
            }
        }
        public void doTranslation() {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
            String eng = edEng.getText().toString();
            //Encodibg String eng
            String urlParams = URLEncoder.encode(eng, "UTF-8");

            new LogInAsyncTaskDictionary(this).execute(new Pair<>(eng, httpClient));
        }
        public void showLoginResult(String result) {
            tv.setText(result);
            edEng.setText("");
        }
    }
```

The servlet I submit the form to returns results as plain text:

```
public class DictionaryServlet extends HttpServlet {

    //'myDictionary' map is a class variable, putting  the initialization in a static initializer:
    public static Map<String, String> myDictionary = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        myDictionary.put("car", "voiture");
        myDictionary.put("house", "maison");
        myDictionary.put("screen", "écran");
        myDictionary.put("computer", "ordinateur");
        myDictionary.put("cup", "verre");
        myDictionary.put("mobile phone", "téléphone portable");
    }
    public DictionaryServlet() {
        super();
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        handleRequest(request, response);
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        handleRequest(request, response);
    }
    private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
            response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String engWord = request.getParameter("eng");

        if (myDictionary.containsKey(engWord)) {
            String frWord = myDictionary.get(engWord);

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setContentLength(frWord.length());
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(frWord);
        }
    }
}
```

and i am using AsyncTask to use the UI thread properly:

```
public class LogInAsyncTaskDictionary extends AsyncTask<Pair<String, HttpClient>, Void, String> {

    private Context context = null;

    public LogInAsyncTaskDictionary(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<String, HttpClient>... params) {

        Pair pair = params[0];
        String urlParams = (String)pair.first;
        HttpClient httpClient = (HttpClient)pair.second;
        try {
            String serverURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Dictionary?" + urlParams;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverURL);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
            return "Wrong: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            //Be sure to catch the ClientProtocolException and IOException thrown.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ((MainActivityDictionary)context).showLoginResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all try with your request with browser. Do you get proper response? Also would be very useful to add logging in your servlet - be sure at least that you getting request, then go deeper and check if you are answering something. Also add logging on your client side.

Comment: I tried this (http://localhost:8080/Dictionary?car), and i get an empty browser!. When i use: http://localhost:8080, i see my servlet but cannot go further!. i went deeper and again i cannot see by myself where i made a mistakes.

Comment: does the servlet receive a proper request ? Dos it even get called properly ? you should debug it a little before asking for help

Comment: like i said i tried everything (on a  browser, debug). i tried many times to bebug my servlet, but i could not figure out the problem. I worked on it for several hours, and i posted my request because i almost gave up!

Comment: you can try some print on the console, and see at least whether the request is fine.you should try to print the request parameters.

Comment: how to do that? i can not use toast or a textView to print the request from the servlet!